# Automating SAPUI5 app - is it possible using its API?

Tags: javascript, automation, sapui5

I'm currently striving to find a way how to automate simple tasks in a SAPUI5 app. I'm used to desktop SAP GUI, which supports scripting and right now I'm trying to do the same in the new frontend.

I'm no expert in JavaScript which makes it more difficult, but I know that using DOM content without the knowledge of underlying sap framework isn't the best option.

I know that I can get certain elements by:

```
var element = sap.ui.getCore().byID(#ID);
```

but I don't know if it is a good approach. I also don't know if I can interact with elements found in that way.

Any hints much appreciated.

Best Regards!

Comment: If you want to automatize something you usually do through a Fiori app, then it can sometimes be a good idea to cut out the middle man and work directly with the underlying oData webservices which are used by the app to communicate with the backend system.

Comment: But if you are looking for the API reference which tells you what you can do with all those UI5 elements: https://ui5.sap.com/#/api

Comment: Thanks for that. I found that api documentation, but since I don't have any experience with building sapui5 apps, I had troubles with finding things that are relevant. What I'd appreciate very much at this stage would be a simple and short example of a straightforward interaction (like clicking on an element for example?). I think I'd be able to take it further from there. I'm of course still reading this documentation. I just wish I knew what I was looking for.

Comment: Can you edit your question to actually ask for such a straightforward interaction? Something like "I have a SAPUI5 button and I know its ID is `buttonXYZ`, how can I simulate a click on it via a javascript one-liner"? Currently your question is very broad and general, so you will only receive broad and general answers.

Comment: Could you point out a direction where I could learn about that oData approach? I know that using console we can trace rest requests, but that's where my knowledge ends.

Comment: Basically it's about reflecting old SAP GUI scripting (VBA) in the new Fiori framework - it's about automating user work (RPA related stuff).